# Component token not getting applied

Tags: antd

Component token siderBg for Layout is not getting applied

I want to change the background color of the sider and i am doing it like this

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      components: {
        Layout: {
          colorBgBase: "green",
          colorBgBody: "red",
          siderBg: "#00FF00",
        },
       
    }}
  >
```

TypeScript is throwing this error

Type '{ colorBgBase: string; colorBgBody: string; siderBg: string; triggerBg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial & Partial & { algorithm?: boolean | MappingAlgorithm | MappingAlgorithm[] | undefined; }'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'siderBg' does not exist in type 'Partial & Partial & { algorithm?: boolean | MappingAlgorithm | MappingAlgorithm[] | undefined; }'.ts(2322)

Comment: The prop `siderBg` does not exists on `Layout` styles because `Sider` is a separated component so you also need to add `Sider` and then add token styles inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of antd in my application and checking version 5.9 docs that's why conflict was happening